# 2.79b YZ rotation widgets are using incorrect AXIS

Tags: axis

I have an issue with rotation, using the 3D manipulator is rotating wrong, The Y manipulator is rotating on the X axis, The Z manipulator is rotating on the Y axis, X axis widget appears to be fine. Using the XYZ keys work as intended, this is only a Manipulator via cursor grab issue

I have reset factory setting, I have uninstalled, checked global and local. I have been searching google but don't really know what to search for to get good results.

[image: System info]

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with your hardware. Can you show us a screenshot or even better a gif explaining this problem?

Comment: Problem https://giphy.com/gifs/8TFmoAEgHjbMMcRXQm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything I could think of, un installing, re installing, deleting Appdata folder, reset to factory settings, log off user and to a new user installing blender, tried 2.77-2.79b nothing helped untill someone linked me
https://blenderartists.org/t/issues-selecting-the-3d-manipulator-arrows/546452/6

gif of problem https://giphy.com/gifs/8TFmoAEgHjbMMcRXQm

Solution: (( User prefs>System tab>Selection (drop down setting)>OpenGL Depth Picking ))

Thank you